# Why Hogwarts teachers did not spot Riddle psychopath tendencies, which could've prevented big tragedy in the future?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

Voldemort was a psychopath, but he was never diagnosed as such, so no appropriate measures were taken to prevent possible future harm to surrounding Hogwarts students. School authorities had every opportunity to spot possible disturbing tendencies, but they didn't.

Why? Is it because he was most teachers' favorite honor student, so they closed their eyes to it? Or psychology science was not developed good enough in magic world vs muggle world? Or Riddle was just that good at masquerading his disturbing tendencies?

Comment: Actually sociopaths act as if they fit in perfectly. It may be hard to spot them and even if some did, it would be hard to pin on him. I guess after Hagrid was fired Dumbledore was very cautious of him. Isn't it why he didn't open chamber of secrets again?

Comment: Which disturbing tendencies do you think they had "every opportunity to spot"? There's no evidence that he did any of the things he'd done at the orphanage while he was a student at Hogwarts. If he did, he hid them from the teachers, including Dumbledore who we knew was keeping a close eye on him.

Comment: @C.Koca I guess the only time he ever showed disturbing tendencies were his dialog with Slughorn about Horcruxes. But Slug is just that dufus of a teacher.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist I agree, but didn't Dumbledore spot it during orphanage scene?

Comment: @VadzimSavenok Yes, because he was doing those things at the orphanage. If he didn't do any of those things at Hogwarts - and there's no evidence that he did, and Dumbledore explicitly told him not to do one of them (steal) - then why would any of the other teachers spot it?

Comment: They have an entire house devoted to training ambitious evil witches and wizards. What makes you think they *didn't* notice?

Comment: For some reason I thought his bad tendencies HAD to come through...

Comment: @Valorum Everyone in the Syltherin house is not evil!!! (Snape, Slughorn). And forgive me but do Slytherins get any other classes apart from rest of the school? Which "Training" are you referring to?

Comment: @dobby - Let's be honest here, it's more than a *little* evil...

Comment: @Valorum Fine majority of the death eaters have belonged to Slytherin but it does't mean the house is to blame for it. Voldemort belonged to it and its natural that he would have gotten most followers from there since he spend his most time among them. And then with Voldemort its like a lifelong contract which stretches to next generations as well e.g. Malfoys, Crabbe, Goyle etc.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist opening the CoS for one. And he was spotted by Dumbledore, he just couldn't/wouldn't do anything about it then

Comment: By the way, Voldemort wasn't a psychopath. They don't show that level of commitment. Hollywood psychopaths aren't *real* psychopaths.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even if the muggles would have taken him to a doctor or wanted to put him in a psych ward they were unsuccessful which is also hinted in the book.

> "I am Professor Dumbledore."
>
> "'Professor'?" repeated Riddle. He looked wary. "Is that like
> 'doctor'? What are you here for? Did she get you in to have a look at
> me?"
>
> He was pointing at the door through which Mrs. Cole had just left.
>
> "I have told you. My name is Professor Dumbledore and I work at a
> school called Hogwarts. I have come to offer you a place at my school
> — your new school, if you would like to come."
>
> Riddle's reaction to this was most surprising. He leapt from the bed
> and backed away from Dumbledore, looking furious.
>
> "You can't kid me! **The asylum, that's where you're from, isn't it?**
> 'Professor,' yes, of course — well, I'm not going, see? That old cat's
> the one who should be in the asylum.
>
> *Half-Blood Prince. Chapter 13: The Secret Riddle*

This clearly suggests that the Orphanage must have tried to get him to see a doctor in the past but as he was very good at "pursuading people"
even back then he must have found a way to avoid it.

Also, he was exceptionally careful and good at hiding his real self from everyone once he came to Hogwarts. Dumbledore had already warned him that "his kind of magic" is not to be tolerated at Hogwarts which made him all the more cautious to act as the perfect poor-but-brilliant Orphan boy.

> "At Hogwarts," Dumbledore went on, "we teach you not only to use
> magic, but to control it. You have — inadvertently, I am sure — been
> using your powers in a way that is neither taught nor tolerated at our
> school. You are not the first, nor will you be the last, to allow your
> magic to run away with you. But you should know that Hogwarts can
> expel students, and the Ministry of Magic — yes, there is a Ministry —
> will punish lawbreakers still more severely.
>
> *Half-Blood Prince. Chapter 13: The Secret Riddle*

Moreover Dumbledore never mentioned his own reservations about Tom Riddle or his encounter with him at the orphanage to any other teacher so they had no reason to keep an eye on him.

> "However, if he was frightening or impressing fellow Slytherins with
> displays of Parseltongue in their common room, no hint of it reached
> the staff. He showed no sign of outward arrogance or aggression at
> all. As an unusually talented and very good-looking orphan, he
> naturally drew attention and sympathy from the staff almost from the
> moment of his arrival. He seemed polite, quiet, and thirsty for
> knowledge. Nearly all were most favorably impressed by him."
>
> "Didn't you tell them, sir, what he'd been like when you met him at
> the orphanage?" asked Harry.
>
> "No, I did not. Though he had shown no hint of remorse, it was
> possible that he felt sorry for how he had behaved before and was
> resolved to turn over a fresh leaf. I chose to give him that chance."
>
> Half Blood Prince: Chapter: Apparition Lessons